# Casting Android Device to Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, android, screencasts, miracast

I am trying to mirror my Android phone/tablet to my Windows 10 PC but am having great difficulty. All my devices are on the same WiFi network. I have followed the instructions on the Microsoft website [[1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/screen-mirroring-and-projecting-to-your-pc-5af9f371-c704-1c7f-8f0d-fa607551d09c#ID0EBD=Windows_10)] for installing the `Connect` app. I have set everything up as it describes---I think! I've set everything to be as open as possible just to try to get it to connect. I have tried a number of other online help pages [[2](https://www.howtogeek.com/269093/how-to-cast-your-windows-or-android-display-to-a-windows-10-pc/), [3](https://www.techsolutions.support.com/how-to/how-to-screen-mirror-android-phone-tablet-to-windows-12652)] and they give basically the same instructions.

I go to `Cast` on my phone (Nokia 3.1 on Android 10) and it simply doesn't find anything.
It works on my tablet (Samsung S6-Lite on Android 11/One UI 3.1) using `Smart View`.

[image: Projecting to this PC settings]

[image: Connect screen]

Comment: `All my devices are on the same WiFi network.` Miracast works over WiFi Direct though. Also, AFAIK, Miracast could be a tricky thing to some WiFi chipset/driver.

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc

Comment: @TomYan Ah, my bad! I thought it was like Chromecast which—unless I'm mistaken again!—*does* require the devices to be on the same network

Comment: @alecxs That's a nice-looking program. It has the added bonus of being able to control the mobile device from the computer. Windows's Connect suggests that it can do that, but I haven't actually be able to make it work on my tablet! The option it says to hit doesn't seem to be there `=P`—anyway, either I'll sort that myself or it's for another question!

Comment: @alecxs I turned on USB debugging, but the same issue is still there. It would seem strange for this to be a requirement; none of the pages I linked suggest that USB debugging is required

Comment: [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) requires usb-debugging. usb-debugging must be authorized (pop-up on phone screen). once connection established you can switch to wireless with *'adb tcpip 5555; adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555'*